# Replacing content after a form is submitted isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to replace the content of a div with the content of a dynamically created page after a search form is submitted. It works fine until I wrap the content in another div. Not sure if this is a CSS issue or a JavaScript issue. So it works fine like this if the content div isn't wrapped in another div.

```
<form id='Myform' method='GET'>
    <input class="input" autocomplete="off" type='search' id='query' name='query' placeholder='Search'>
    <input class="submit" type='submit' value='Search'>
</form>

<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
$( document ).on( "submit", "#Myform", function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: $(this).attr('GET'),
        success: function(response) {
            var success =  $($.parseHTML(response)).filter(".content"); 
            $('.content').replaceWith(success);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

But then if I wrap the content div in a container, even if I don't add any CSS to the container--just putting a div around it--the script no longer works so if I do this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It breaks the script. And I am not really sure why this is happening.

Comment: `$(this).attr('GET')` should be `$(this).attr('method')`

Comment: what is the value of `response`

Comment: If the problem persists even without any CSS, that's a pretty good indicator that it's not a CSS issue ;-)

Comment: I tried this out and still nothing the content div just comes up blank

Comment: Try `var success =  $($.parseHTML(response)).find(".content"); `

Comment: Lol, the ajax object is doing absolutely nothing. You haven't given it a location for a request. It sends data, sets the type and provides a callback to ... nothing. You might need a `url`

Comment: So I used var success = $($.parseHTML(response)).find(".content");  and needed to ad the  url : "localhost:8888/projects/source/" and it seems to be working now.  If you want to put this as an answer I will check it as working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the working code I needed to use

```
var success = $($.parseHTML(response)).find(".content");
```

and specify the url

```
url : "myURL"
```

Here it is in full

```
<form id='Myform' method='GET'>
    <input class="input" autocomplete="off" type='search' id='query' name='query' placeholder='Search'>
    <input class="submit" type='submit' value='Search'>
</form>

<div class="content">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
$( document ).on( "submit", "#Myform", function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: $(this).attr('GET'),
        url : "myURL"
        success: function(response) {
            var success = $($.parseHTML(response)).find(".content");
            $('.content').replaceWith(success);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```